# How to create a music CD from mp3 files?

Tags: software-recommendation, burning

Are there any Nero Burning Softwares for Ubuntu ? The most important is to able burn Mp3 or songs files into the CD/DVD =)

Answer (score 33):

### Brasero

[image]

Brasero is a simple application to burn, copy and erase CD and DVD
media: audio, video or data. To install Brasero in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install brasero
```

Brasero is installed by default with Ubuntu. It has a simple interface, but powerful features.

Some of them:

**Data CD/DVD:**

- supports edition of discs contents (remove/move/rename files inside directories)
- can burn data CD/DVD on the fly
- automatic filtering for unwanted files (hidden files, broken/recursive symlinks, files not conforming to joliet standard, ...)
- supports multisession
- supports joliet extension
- can write the image to the hard drive
- can check disc file integrity

**Audio CD:**

- write CD-TEXT information (automatically found thanks to gstreamer)
- supports the edition of CD-TEXT information
- can burn audio CD on the fly
- can use all audio files handled by Gstreamer local installation (ogg, flac, mp3, ...)
- can search for audio files inside dropped folders
- full edition of silences between tracks

**CD/DVD copy:**

- can copy a CD/DVD to the hard drive
- can copy CD and DVD on the fly
- supports single-session data DVD
- supports any kind of CD

If it's not already in your system, you can install it easily via Software Center, or, via command line with `sudo apt-get install brasero`.

Comment: Turns out it was already installed on my Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Brasero does not work here in 2019.

Answer (score 22):

**[K3b](https://userbase.kde.org/K3b)** is my favorite burning application for Linux. K3b's interface would be very familiar to someone with a background in Nero on Windows. I heartily recommend K3b. [Click here to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/k3b) or run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

I have had trouble with Brasero making coasters in the past, and its minimal approach to output prevented me from discerning why.

Comment: I also vote for k3b. Never looked back to Brasero after using it.

Comment: used it first time ever and burnt a CD without any problems. very intuitive to use, very happy to have followed your advice! thanks!

Comment: All the CDs I make with k3b show up as "No Disk" in my CD player. It seems like it is making an mp3 cd instead of a music cd.

Answer (score 7):

Default Ubuntu's CD Burning Brasero can utilize that,. it is integrating in nautilus to. try to copy paste your music collection into your mounted blank CD / DVD. and then burn it on nautilus extra menu.

Comment: @Wilsonzaizai: If squallbayu or Decio's answer solved your problem, click the one of the checkmarks under the upvote/downvote arrows to let other people know that it solved it :)

Answer (score 3):

k3b is KDE based, but probably the best CD burning software I've seen to date on linux.  Also.. if you really want Nero, they do have/had a linux version.  http://www.nero.com/enu/linux4.html

Comment: Wow , i didn know that Nero has an alternative for Linux too , i thought its only for windows . Thanks !

Comment: I am using it, actually. It's  what I would call a scaled-down version, but it works fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it the Ubuntu way: just drag and drop your **playlist** (or your audio files) to the empty CD and burn. Done. Never been easier :-)

Comment: Oh , using Ryhthmbox or Banshe ??

Comment: does not really matter. Try guayadeque or exaile.

Comment: If he's happy with Rhythmbox/Banshee, no reason to recommend that he switch :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you were looking for a command-line only solution, you can use directly the following:

```
$ burn -A -a *.mp3
```

In case you need to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install burn
```

Usually, the steps to create an audio CD from a set of *.mp3 are usually more complex, so `burn` is much easier to use (no complex option or heavy UI to start up).

For reference, a more advanced tutorial:

```
# apt-get install cdrecord ffmpeg normalize-audio libavcodec52
```

if names of your files contain a space use this command to replace space with _:

```
$ for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr ' ' '_'`; done
```

Convert all files to wav format, normalize wav and burn:

```
$ for i in $( ls ); do ffmpeg -i $i $i.wav; done
$ normalize-audio -m *.wav
$ cdrecord -v -fix -eject dev='/dev/scd0' -audio -pad *.wav
```

- https://linuxconfig.org/burn-your-music-files-from-any-format-to-audio-cd-using-command-line