# Alternative to CD/DVD Creator

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, dvd

Is there an alternative to CD/DVD Creator that I can install or enable so that I never have to see that program again.

I don't like that it looks very much like a regular Ubuntu/Gnome directory browser.  The default behavior has it that any files burned to DVD remain and the user has to manually delete them.  Even when you insert a blank DVD it is not recognized as blank and you have to delete the file you burned previously.  This is not a nice user interface because it forces the user to delete important files from a window that looks very much like a regular folder viewer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nero Alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7543/nero-alternatives)

Comment: This site is not the appropriate place to place rants or ask for changes or features. It is just to answer questions, your ideas will be lost and are not going to be discussed. Your should probably discuss this in the forums (http://ubuntuforums.org/) and open a bug if you found some support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you try [brasero](http://projects.gnome.org/brasero//index.html) or the well-known [k3b](http://www.k3b.org/).

I've used both of them for quite some times.

I think that k3b is superior in terms of stability, but to be honest, as i Gnome user, i don't like having to add the QT libraries (as k3b was built for KDE) on my machine.