# Repair silent CD

Tags: cd

I have a CD from a friend that was imported from India. I can see files when I open it with the PC and listen to them, but putting it in the CD Player gives no joy. What can be done to restore this music for my friend? He is post retirement age and doesn't want to learn new tricks, like playing it from his computer.

Comment: We Appreciate you coming to Ubuntu with this question but copying Music files from a CD is the capability of any OS. Could you be more specific as to what you want to do? Copy from CD and then Burn onto a new CD?

Comment: Possibly related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/7543/how-to-create-a-music-cd-from-mp3-files  What format are the music files in? Mp3?

Comment: Yes they are .mp3 files

Comment: The CD my friend gave won't play in his player. I want to do whatever necessary to return him something he can listen to in his player. I tried Brasario to make an image and then burn, but still could not play. I only use non ubuntu OS's for my taxes.

Comment: It's not new technology but a lot of CD Players won't support MP3 format. See The link above or try this one. https://itstillworks.com/convert-mp3-audio-cd-format-1479.html